# How to create a nested SQL Query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, t-sql, select, nested

When writing the below query, it complains that the "so.id" column is unknown! The below query works fine in MS SQL but not in MySQL? How to write a nested select statement in MySQL?

What's the equivalent for it?

```
    select so.*  
from smart_objects as so
    inner join (
        SELECT  st.objectid, st.issueid
        FROM smart_targets as st            
        WHERE st.issueid != 0
            AND
            (   (st.objectid = so.id)
                OR 
                (               
                st.objectid in (
                    SELECT sor.parent 
                    FROM smart_objectrelations as sor       
                    WHERE sor.child = so.id)
                )
            )) as soi
    on soi.objectid = so.id
where so.id < 100;
```

I'd need to inner join a nested Select SQL basically. My select statement is more complex than above, the above is just a simplified version to explain about nested tables.

I also tried the other suggestion:

```
select so.*  
    from smart_objects as so
        inner join (
            SELECT  st.objectid, st.issueid
            FROM smart_targets as st, smart_objects as so           
            WHERE st.issueid != 0
                AND
                (   (st.objectid = so.id)
                    OR 
                    (               
                    st.objectid in (
                        SELECT sor.parent 
                        FROM smart_objectrelations as sor       
                        WHERE sor.child = so.id)
                    )
                )) as soi
        on soi.objectid = so.id
    where so.id < 100;
```

The above code goes into a never-ending loop whereas I simply want the nested sql to run for every row of the parent.

UPDATED with ANSWER:

How'd you simplify the below query?

```
select so.* 
from smart_objects as so
    inner join (
        SELECT  st.objectid, st.issueid
        FROM smart_targets as st, smart_objects as so           
        WHERE st.objectid = so.id
            and st.issueid != 0
            AND
            (   (st.objectid = so.id)
                OR 
                (               
                st.objectid in (
                    SELECT sor.parent 
                    FROM smart_objectrelations as sor, smart_objects as so      
                    WHERE sor.child = so.id)
                )
            )
        ) as soi
    on soi.objectid = so.id
```

Comment: Is it really working in MS SQL? This fiddle works in neither MySQL nor MS SQL 2008 or 2012: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f32ce/1

Comment: Sorry, but how can the problem be BOTH that so.id is unknown and that the query triggers an infinite loop?

Comment: Updated. how'd you create nested select statements in MySQL? How'd you run another select statement with every record of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : I guess this should work

```
 select so.*  
    from smart_objects as so
    inner join (SELECT  st.objectid, st.issueid FROM smart_targets as st,smart_objects as so          
        WHERE st.objectid = so.id) as soi
    on soi.objectid = so.id
```

Comment: but it'd be having a different meaning though? I'd like the nested Select to run with each parent row.